# Firebase Auth uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

I'm trying to start my flutter application using `flutter run` but am getting an error when I do.

The following error shows:

`Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.5.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.`

`Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.`

I've looked up some fixes, mostly people saying that the versions are outdated, not the case (`Flutter version: 0.4.4 beta`, `Firebase version: 0.5.10`).

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: you can still compile, right?

Comment: @Tree Yes, can compile but when the app launches it stops again

Comment: This is just a warning, I think it has nothing to do with your app stopping. I could be wrong, but usually in plugins you only ignore the warnings. Are you sure you have no other problems in your app?

Comment: @Tree The weird thing is, the app worked while using the 'hot reload'. After actually closing the app and 'injecting' the new dependency (`flutter run`) it stopped working

Comment: ah, Do flutter clean

Comment: @Tree Tried it, unfortunately didn't help

Comment: very strange. I run latest firebase with beta flutter and it all works fine. Try to do flutter pub cache repair maybe.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20486) worked for me, but I don't know how!

Answer (score 0):

The "overrides deprecated API" message is just a warning and it shouldn't cause the app to stop running. I also encountered using FlutterFire plugins with these warnings thrown at times. Posting the stack trace from the app and logs from `flutter doctor --verbose` will help us identify why the app stops.